# Can't convert dates to datetime64

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

The following piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'date': ('13/02/2012', '14/02/2012')})
data['date'] = data['date'].astype('datetime64')
```

works fine on one machine (windows) and doesn't work on another (linux). Both numpy and pandas are installed on both.

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: Cannot create a NumPy datetime other than NaT with generic units
```

What does this error mean? I see it for the first time ever and there is not much on the web I can find. Is it some missing dependency?

Comment: Are the numpy versions the same on both machines?  (`print np.__version__`).  If I remember correctly, `datetime64` is a pretty recent addition.

Comment: 1.6.2 on machine where it works and 1.7.0 on another one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do this instead. Pandas keeps datestimes internally as `datetime64[ns]`. Conversions
like this are very buggy (because of issues in various numpy version, 1.6.2 especially). Use 
the pandas routines, then operate like thesee are actual datetime objects. What are you trying to do?

```
In [30]: pandas.to_datetime(data['date'])
Out[30]: 
0   2012-02-13 00:00:00
1   2012-02-14 00:00:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks! I just have a file with dates as strings and so converting them to objects with which I can work... Cheers :)

Comment: ha....also can try passing ``parse_dates=True`` to read_csv (more options in the docs as well)

Comment: Yep, I avoided that one because there are some date-similar strings which I didn't want to convert.

Comment: makes sense, only recommendation on that is too create 2 columns then, moving date-similar to another column, and filling this one with ``NaT`` where they were (as easy as ``s[indexes_of_moved_columns] = np.nan``, which will convert to ``NaT`` when the columns is ``datetime64[ns]``), my2c